# VIEW created in MySQL giving wrong output with SELECT

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm creating a database for a courtier company and I have 5 relations

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
cid int(7) NOT NULL,
cfname char(25) NOT NULL, 
clname char(25) NOT NULL, 
aptnum int(100) NOT NULL,
street char(50) NOT NULL, 
pobox int(10) NOT NULL,
area char(50) NOT NULL, 
country char(50) NOT NULL, 
phone int(12) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (cid)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Orderr
(
orderid int(8) NOT NULL, 
origin char(100) NOT NULL, 
destination char(100) NOT NULL, 
eta date NOT NULL, 
weight int(100) NOT NULL,
priority enum('F','R') NOT NULL,
task enum('P','D') NOT NULL, 
odate date NOT NULL, 
cnum int(12) NOT NULL, 
cpin int(8) NOT NULL,
custid int(7) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (orderid),
FOREIGN KEY (custid) REFERENCES Customer(cid)
)ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE History 
(
histid int(6) NOT NULL, 
orderid int(8) NOT NULL, 
status enum('D','O','R') NOT NULL, 
current_loc char(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(histid), 
FOREIGN KEY (orderid) REFERENCES Orderr(orderid)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Driver
(
driverid int(6) NOT NULL,
dfname varchar(25) NOT NULL,
dlname varchar(25) NOT NULL,
dob date NOT NULL,
phone int(10) NOT NULL,
vehicle int(6) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (driverid)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Vehicle
(
vid int(6) NOT NULL, 
num_plate varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
vtype enum('T','B','P') NOT NULL,
driverr int(6) NOT NULL,
orders int(8) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (vid),
FOREIGN KEY (driverr) REFERENCES Driver(driverid),
FOREIGN KEY (orders) REFERENCES Orderr(orderid)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I am trying to create a VIEW for the Customer giving access to specific columns, here is the query

```
CREATE VIEW CustView AS
SELECT cfname, clname, aptnum, street, pobox, area, country, origin, destination, weight, priority, task, eta, odate, dfname, dlname, driver.phone
FROM Customer, Orderr, Vehicle, Driver
WHERE Customer.cid=Orderr.custid AND Vehicle.driverr=Driver.driverid AND Orderr.orderid=Vehicle.orders;
```

When I run `SELECT * FROM CustView` I do not get the desired output. What changes if any should I make to my query or perhaps to my relations?

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't tell us what the desired output *is*, how can we tell you what changes need to be made?

Comment: For starters, ditch the old school comma syntax for the join operations. Use the `JOIN` keyword and move the join predicates to the `ON` clause. Also, *qualify* all column references with the table name, or a table alias. Get a SELECT statement that returns the "desired output" *before* you put it into a `CREATE VIEW` statement. As far as what other changes that are needed to your `SELECT`, doesn't that really depend on what it is you want returned? Without a specification, example data, and a description of what makes the output undesirable, we're just guessing.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thank you so much for your insight. I'm still learning MySQL from college and I still got lots to learn. I'll keep these tips in mind next time I create the tables.

Comment: Does the `SELECT` inside the `VIEW` definition produce the same incorrect data?  If so, then `VIEW` is a red herring, and should be removed from the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous posters remarked, I can only guess. But from your table and view definition, I get the suspicion that you didn't model the relation between Vehicle and Order properly. A Vehicle can be used for many Orders, right? In this case, the Vehicle id must be a foreign key in the Order table. Your design is just the other way round.

Not related to your question, I am suspicious of your History table. The history of orders fulfilled comprises just those orders which are in the past, right? So the history would be just a view that selects orders by past values of some of the dates contained therein.